# Is it possible to make a statement without involving time?

Tags: verbs, tense

All verbs seem to assume time. Is, was, will be, etc. I don't mean specific times, but the concept of time in general. Is it possible to make any statement without involving time?

Comment: “Me Tarzan, you Jane”? But no, it isn’t. Time is a part of the physical world we inhabit, and it’s not possible to make a statement without involving it, at the very least as known background info. Even if there’s no overt reference to time (like in the Tarzan-Jane example or in languages that don’t mark verbal tense morphologically), there’s an inherent reference to our shared knowledge that time exists and passes.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is there a word for that? What would we call a concept that is unavoidable and/or necessary for making statements?

Comment: Not specifically, that I know of. It’s a type of presupposition, I guess, but that’s a broader term (and one that has different meanings in different fields).

Answer (score 3):

English in particular requires all verbs to be marked for tense, either "past" or "non-past". Some other languages don't; in Mandarin, for example, there's no need to include the tense as part of the verb.

Even in English, though, it's possible to construct sentences that don't imply any particular time. "Gnomic" statements, for example, indicate that something is universally or always true, rather than true at any specific point in time: "the cats are eating" talks about the state of the world right now, but "cats eat" is a timeless truth.

Comment: "Gnomic" Thank you. That's very helpful. But what if cats don't eat in the future? Are we assuming they always have and always will? Seems like this gets philosophical right away.

Comment: The question is not whether cats will always eat, the question is what "cats eat" linguistically asserts.

Comment: @user6726 and then whether that assertion involves time.

Comment: [Also called "generic"](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/generics.html). There are generic verb phrases, like _That dog bites_ or _Bill walks to work_, and there are generic noun phrases, too, like _The tiger is extinct in Europe_ or _A madrigal is polyphonic_. As to whether it involves time, not specifically -- the distinction is between repetition or continuity as opposed to one-off-hood.

Comment: The point is that statement entails many universally quantified sub-propositions like "at all times", "in all places", "of all colors". Time is not specified as part of the proposition, unlike the assertion "The cat died yesterday".

Comment: @user6726 "At all times" is what I was getting at. Whether it's temporarily or permanently true, both seem to rely on the general concept of time/temporality (not specific times).

Comment: Would you then agree that the statement involves colors and places? They are equally involved, in being compatible with the statement.

Comment: @user6726 That seems possible. Attempting to rephrase it I came up with "eating is something cats do." Probably not identical, but that's essentially what I'm hearing with regard to time in "cats eat."